# New window opens on click but does not show anything[Tkinter]

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am using root as the primary window in which when one puts a question, then the answer from either Wikipedia or WolframAlpha is shown in a new window. But, here what happens is that the new window properly opens but does not show anything.

```
from Tkinter import *
import wolframalpha
import wikipedia

root=Tk()
root1=Tk()

def getinput():
    global entry
    answer = StringVar()
    ques=entry.get()
    try:
        #wolframalpha
        app_id = myappid #value of myappid is there in the original code
        client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)
        res = client.query(ques)
        answer.set(next(res.results).text)
        label=Label(root1, textvariable=answer)

    except:
        #wikipedia
        answer.set(wikipedia.summary(ques).encode('utf-8'))
        label=Label(root1, textvariable=answer)
    label.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.geometry("350x80+300+300")
label=Label(root, text="Hi! I am Python Digital Assistant. How can I help you today?")
entry=Entry(root)
submit=Button(root, text="Submit", bg="light green", command=getinput)

exit1=Button(root, text="Exit", bg="red", fg="white", command=root.destroy)

label.pack()
entry.pack(fill=X)
entry.focus_set()
submit.pack(side=LEFT)
exit1.pack(side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call `TK` twice you have to use `toplevel` to achieve that , with that when you provide the question and click on the `submit` method the answer will pop up in the `Toplevel` window.

```
from Tkinter import *
import wolframalpha
import wikipedia

root=Tk()


def getinput():

    top = Toplevel()
    top.geometry("500x500")
    global entry
    answer = StringVar()
    ques=entry.get()
    try:
        #wolframalpha
        app_id = myappid #value of myappid is there in the original code
        client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)
        res = client.query(ques)
        answer.set(next(res.results).text)
        label=Label(top, textvariable=answer)

    except:
        #wikipedia
        answer.set(wikipedia.summary(ques).encode('utf-8'))
        label=Label(top, textvariable=answer)
    label.pack(side=TOP)

root.geometry("350x80+300+300")
label=Label(root, text="Hi! I am Python Digital Assistant. How can I help you today?")
entry=Entry(root)
submit=Button(root, text="Submit", bg="light green", command=getinput)

exit1=Button(root, text="Exit", bg="red", fg="white", command=root.destroy)

label.pack()
entry.pack(fill=X)
entry.focus_set()
submit.pack(side=LEFT)
exit1.pack(side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: result]